# Cant complete my first push on GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, permission-denied, gitlab

i have my gitlab running on an internal server which is publish to the outside using port redirection, i am able to: log into gitlab, create user, create new projects, grant privileges to user. But when i try to push my first project with this line from my local machine terminal (Ubuntu):

```
git push -u origin master
```

the prompt is showed, asking my for the password of git@domain.com, i enter the password of the git user but the permision is dennied and finally the next message is shown:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The ssh port for the gitlab server is not the default (22), i have been reading and triyng many suggestion but not of them had helped me.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up your ssh config file to take care of the connection details. For example, edit `~/.ssh/config` to contain

```
Host yourgitdomain.com
   Port 2222
```

Comment: Now the problem seems to be a bit different, it is supposed that i should use my gitlab user password on the prompt git@domain.com but i am getting "Permission denied, please try again."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup your ssh key properly.
and do a sudo su root, and then do the git pull, clone or push.